# Anova in scipy with nan output

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I'm trying to run the f_oneway function in scipy.

Basically, I have 3 dataframes representing respectively 3 groups and I want to perform ANOVA  among axis=1.

```
from scipy.stats import f_oneway
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
group1 = {'1': {0: 574145.477641226, 1: 1570531.589742876, 2: 787929.7027375237, 3: 2570860.248729332, 4: 161008.90274193016, 5: np.nan, 6: 1027027.5447738492, 7: 10620164.126712576, 8: 3030551.86415567, 9: 6080226.794887304}, '2': {0: 5590292.274747584, 1: 2015192.4244239724, 2: 1442638.778579319, 3: 9484756.854645137, 4: 231213.53284854395, 5: 1576095.5497571388, 6: 853517.4230997175, 7: 13701076.997994969, 8: 880909.9414626792,9: 10973682.322579961}, '3': {0: 1786259.070812378, 1: 1188813.4685229606, 2: 280628.96027922264, 3: 2752454.6157454816, 4: 142423.39853381264, 5: 408643.1442709076, 6: 978859.742220046, 7: 8581569.49299859, 8: 2810091.19540494, 9: 3250847.2113601067}, '4': {0: 1423158.826220004, 1: np.nan, 2: 659142.6504867233, 3: 2727740.4095105752, 4: np.nan, 5: np.nan, 6: 166867.88656477776, 7: 15578367.076207979, 8: 1262229.6767083204, 9: 7537134.164088669}}

group2 = {'1': {0: 1108031.2785915325, 1: 39475.12143335618, 2: 124744.55052420696, 3: 3415955.3418994714, 4: np.nan, 5: np.nan, 6: 1185929.1264358065, 7: 14219856.696859175, 8: 107938.85576451271, 9: 9075885.57144011}, '2': {0: 3711668.7595074927, 1: np.nan, 2: 92069.12449997541, 3: 1430920.365911842, 4: 23305.980330372353, 5: 146884.88381736717, 6: 143162.52169470832, 7: 11043912.321755221,8: 1507299.549731886, 9: 6675740.20722453}, '3': {0: np.nan, 1: np.nan, 2: np.nan, 3: 192966.31343644214, 4: np.nan, 5: np.nan, 6: np.nan, 7: 13478434.128944362, 8: np.nan, 9: np.nan}, '4': {0: 6446934.0065947445, 1: 3195385.066201132, 2: 3332326.9653299027, 3: 7082529.01041953, 4: 139891.94206563127, 5: 208662.14176584402, 6: 2559284.7669506934, 7: 7395774.107780765, 8: 415796.834504837, 9: 9502289.070542539}}
group3 = {'1': {0: 5832002.081448822, 1: 2607987.6485992945, 2: 2465656.4470221293, 3: 6077038.510021252, 4: 391523.2907555177, 5: np.nan, 6: 2590061.00923242, 7: 7982067.848957288, 8: 61836.18519446156, 9: 10673885.385156194}, '2': {0: 4515593.798793708, 1: 2070893.600738691, 2: 1788619.7598766778, 3: 7302148.61285157, 4: 132247.07494014164, 5: 2130531.009443398, 6: 849079.4122880008, 7: 11086507.936560597, 8: np.nan, 9: 8977041.57285477}, '3': {0: 6916739.909404968, 1: 2886026.824106484, 2: 871822.3682870092, 3: 6515743.347648245, 4: 347767.01169986156, 5: 2975827.5336636542, 6: 3270053.676901515, 7: 9230036.81889698, 8: 4753111.521553177, 9: 11835765.28309747}, '4': {0: 8918243.297089897, 1: 2631751.3775385492, 2: 2294251.0955892503, 3: 7540353.19469351, 4: 48925.64795198818, 5: 447721.0646689915, 6: 1682494.645617865, 7: 6945276.49780706, 8: 978022.2657575278, 9: 11631856.25162219}}

groups = [group1, group2, group3]
data = [pd.DataFrame(x) for x in groups]
result = f_oneway(*data, axis=1)
result
```

The result output is:

> pvalue=array([nan, nan, nan, 0.17318404, nan, nan, nan, 0.24112312, nan, nan])

The nan p-value is probably due to the NaN also present in my datasets, requiring an analysis omitting the NaN. So, I tried:

```
groups = [group1, group2, group3]
data = [pd.DataFrame(x) for x in groups]
data_test = []
for i in data:
     df = i.to_numpy()
     df = [x[~np.isnan(x)] for x in df]
     data_test.append(df)
from scipy.stats import f_oneway
result = f_oneway(*data_test, axis=1)
result
```

And the output was:

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested
> array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected
> shape was (10,) + inhomogeneous part.

Someone knows how can I perform an ANOVA with same performance than scipy but ommiting NaN from original samples?

Answer (score 1):

Within each sample, you are deleting an uneven amount of np.NaN values per column, meaning that each sample ends up as a ragged (inhomogenuous) array. usually with missing values in table type structures you must either

**Drop the whole column** - this is often not helpful but depends on the subject studied.

**Drop the whole row** - often less drastic, but you may need to check how much data you have left.

**Impute data** - fill with a default or minimum value or rolling average or some other method of adding guessed values.

Pandas has many functions for handling missing values and there are [many online guides](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/working-with-missing-data-in-pandas/). Here we drop all rows with a missing value

```
groups = [group1, group2, group3]
data = [pd.DataFrame(x).dropna(axis='index') for x in groups]
from scipy.stats import f_oneway
result = f_oneway(*data, axis=1)
result
```

Comment: Thanks ciaran. I was wondering if there is anything similar to scipy ttest_ind, which we can omit the NaN values

Comment: Hi, not to my knowledge I'm afraid.